# user agent returns null when the client uses wcf test client

Tags: c#, wcf

I want to log the user agents information in my log file. So I use this code:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent;
```

It works fine when I'm using the browser to consume my web service (the user agent returns the right value) but when I use the WCF test client, it returns null string.
In IIS log file user agent returns right value no matter use which application to consume the web service.
I guess I miss something here but I don't now what.

Comment: Have you tried to get the User-Agent via `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["user-agent"]`?